# Xubuntu 14.04.3 - Monitors turn of during boot

Tags: boot, xubuntu, monitor

After installing Xubuntu 14.04.3, I can not boot into the system. Instead, after selecting ubuntu within the grub menu and pressing enter, a few messages are shown and the monitor turns of after approximately 2 seconds.

I tried without success:

- booting to Recovery mode
- DVI/HDMI/VGA outlets
- multiple installs (without downloading updates/third party software)
- several boot options including "nomodeset" and "text"

The live-usb is working fine (typing from it just now). I was able to acces dmesg earlier from live-usb, the last message being that alsa was loaded. Now it only reads "(Nothing has been logged yet.)".
I have newly built the concerning PC with the following hardware.

- AMD A10-7850
- 16GB ADATA DDR3 2133
- MSI A88XI AC V2
- Samsung 850 Pro 128 GB

Memtest is running fine without any errors.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: By chance were you using Catalyst?

Comment: It is normal for the monitor to stop receiving a video signal during boot. However, it should start receiving video soon after. If you turn on your monitor manually, isn't the system simply still booting? Perhaps your monitor is set to time out a little too soon.

Comment: I don't think thats the problem, catalyst might be used if third party software is enabled, but I also tried without, where it should not be used.

Comment: Had the system running for approx. 20min after the monitor turned of (standby) to see if it turns on again, it doesn't.  I also plugged out the power cable and put it back in to see if it would help, but no change :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some more experimenting, it seems to be some kind of hardware issue. When I deactivate the Turbo Core Feature in the BIOS (increased CPU frequency from 3.7 to 4 Ghz) then the System is starting fine. If I then install the fglrx-drivers (which are also meddling with the frequency, I think) I can boot into xubuntu, but the system crashes after a few seconds.

So without the fglrx drivers and with deactivated Turbo Core, the system seems to be stable. I am running mprime now just to make sure, but I might have to return the CPU to my dealer.

Edit: Turns out, the CPU was not the Problem. I had te disable "Core C6 state" in the BIOS. This is a deep sleep mode where some cores can temporarily be turned off completely. It seems like this is not working properly on my board. With a new processor and the option enableded, I could hardly boot @ 1Ghz and the machine was only somewhat stable. With the option disabled I had mprime running without any errors for 10h now @3.7Ghz with Turbo Core enabled.

Thanks again for all your advice.

Thanks for your effort & ideas !